# xlutils.copy [python 2.7 - excel]

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlutils

I'm new to python (and to programming in general).

I am having a problem using `xlrd`, `xlwt` and `xlutils` for accessing an **xlsx** workbook (it is a common question but i did not find any solution for me).

Should I change my package for `py-excel`?
In that case, which one?

Here is my code:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy as xlutils_copy

rd = xlrd.open_workbook("x:/PROJECTS/Papers/2014_Pasture/a.xlsx")
rdsh = rd.sheet_by_name("FR_PASTURE")

wrb = xlutils_copy(rd)
ws = wrb.get_sheet_by_name("FR_PASTURE")
```

And the error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\PROJECTS\Papers\2014_Pasture\AdjustXLSStats.py", line 28, in <module>
    wrb = xlutils_copy(rd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.0-py2.7.egg\xlutils\copy.py", line 19, in copy
    w
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.0-py2.7.egg\xlutils\filter.py", line 937, in process
    reader(chain[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.0-py2.7.egg\xlutils\filter.py", line 68, in __call__
    filter.cell(row_x,col_x,row_x,col_x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.0-py2.7.egg\xlutils\filter.py", line 573, in cell
    wtrow.set_cell_number(wtcolx, cell.value, style)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\xlwt\Row.py", line 203, in set_cell_number
    self.__adjust_bound_col_idx(colx)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\xlwt\Row.py", line 78, in __adjust_bound_col_idx
    raise ValueError("column index (%r) not an int in range(256)" % arg)
ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256)
```

---

Version of xlutils installed : 1.7.0
OS: windows 8 
excel: office 20113

Comment: How many columns are there in your xlsx file?

Comment: Tnx for posting the question. XLrd xlwt xlutils are for xls and not xlsx... so i find a solution in using openpyxl

Comment: @Krasto Great that you have found the solution. Post it as an answer, it would serve others in future. Or add it as final part of your question titled "solution".

Comment: @JanVlcinsky While browsing old unanswered questions I made a community wiki answer, if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlrd`, `xlwt`, and `xlutils` are for accessing **xls** files, and have not been updated for use with **xlsx** files, which results in your multiple errors.

As a workaround, there is now a Python library [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)which can easily read and write Excel `xlsx`/`xlsm`/`xltx`/`xltm` files.